# Calling an interface from an interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on a project which has some legacy code and I'm not sure how certain interfaces interact with each other.

There are two interfaces, that look something like this:

```
public interface FirstInterface {
     void someFunction();
}
```

And the second one which calls (?) the first one:

```
public interface SecondInterface {
     FirstInterface fi();
}
```

I'm new to Java and I don't understand if this is some form of nested interface or if something else is going on here. I'm also not sure if `FirstInterface fi()` calls the interface or creates a method of that type and if so what is the advantage over doing something like `FirstInterface fi`? If it helps, both these interfaces are in different packages.

If I can add any information to make this clearer, please let me know and thank you!

Comment: `FirstInterface fi();` is defining a method `fi` that returns an object of type `FirstInterface`

Comment: thanks for your comment @Smutje, I have a follow-up and this probably varies from case to case but what is the advantage of having a method with an interface as the return type instead of something like implementing the interface and accessing any internal function?

Comment: Regarding follow-up: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947)

Comment: The fact the return type is derived from an interface isn't necessarily relevant. It is a return type just like anything else. If the interface had a method `int getInt();` that would seem normal. `Object getObject();` ? `Runnable getRunnable();` where Runnable is also an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces in java are used for **polymorphism**. The key point is that **interfaces are only definitions not implementations**. These declarations are also called method signatures as they declares the name, return-type and parameters of the method.

In your code `FirstInterface` only declares a method which doesn't return anything. On the other hand `SecondInterface` declares a method which returns an object of type `FirstInterface`. But as I said, these are only declarations. These interfaces are implemented by Classes where we define their body.
I think nothing is better than a code snippet. So consider this example:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    void meathod1();
    int meathod2();
    String meathod3();
}

public interface MyInterface2{
    MyInterface meathod4();
}

public class Class A implements MyInterface{
    public void meathod1(){     
    } 

    public Integer meathod2(){
        return 0;       
    }

    public String meathod3(){       
        return "Apple";
    }
}

public class Class B implements MyInterface{
    public void meathod1(){     
    } 

    public Integer meathod2(){
        return 1;       
    }

    public String meathod3(){       
        return "Banana";
    }
}

public class Class C implements MyInterface2{
    public MyInterface meathod4(){
        MyInterface myInterface = new A();
        return myInterface;
    }
}
```

Here `MyInterface` and MyInterface2 are 2 interfaces. First one declares 3 methods which return nothing, integer and String respectively. Second interface declares method which returns object of type `MyInterface`.

`MyInterface` is implemented by 2 classes namely `A` and `B`. Both of them assign definitions to the methods as per their needs.

MyInterface2 is implemented by Class `C`, which creates an reference `myInterface` of type `MyInterface`. Because `MyInterface` was implemented by classes `A` and `B`, it can point to object of either of them. In the code above we made an object from class `A` and associate it with `myInterface`. Finally we return it as specified by the method signature. This is similar to what happening in your code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces need to be implemented. So there will be a class, say FirstClass, defined something like this:

```
class FirstClass implements FirstInterface {
    public void someFunction() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

and another class that implements SecondInterface. Notice from the syntax that the method `fi()` *returns* an instance of `FirstInterface`; it does not call it. In fact, you can't call an interface (or a class): you can only call methods.

To return an instance of `FirstInterface`, the `fi()` method must create an object of a class that implements it (such as FirstClass), and return that object. As an exercise, you might want to try writing a class `SecondClass` and its `fi()` method.